# How to only use terminal to connect to a wifi hotspot which requires webpage login?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, internet

I have a server machine running at home. It has two network interfaces: cable LAN, and a WLAN.

I ssh into this machine using its cabel LAN interface, because it is stable and robust.

I need to use this server to download large dataset. But downloading hogs my bandwidth, making my ssh connection not responsive.

However, there exist an separate WIFI hotspot (xfinitywifi) which is independent of my cable LAN. I want to use my WLAN interface to connect to this WIFI hotspot. And download only using this WLAN interface. This will keep my cable LAN interface dedicated to ssh connection.

The question is: this WIFI hotspot requires a webpage login. How do I connect to a WIFI hotspot using only terminal? `nmcli`, `nmtui` I have looked into these. But they can help with WPA user_id/password, but not web-page login. Any idea?